# Mailchimp "invalid_grant" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, mailchimp

I'm trying to complete authentication with Mailchimp's OAuth
implementation, and my access token request is getting an
"invalid_grant" error.

Using the ruby HTTParty gem, I'm POSTing data to Mailchimp:

```
  url = 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token'
  result = HTTParty.post(url,
                         body: {
                            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                            client_id: ENV["MAILCHIMP_ID"],
                            client_secret: ENV["MAILCHIMP_SECRET"],
                            code: auth_hash.credentials.token,
                            redirect_uri: 'https://requestb.in/1jrbjmi1',
                         },
                         headers: {
                            'Accept': 'application/json'
                         })
```

Where:

- grant_type is 'authorization_code'
- client id & secret are the values given to me when I set up my app
  at the Mailchimp
- code is the token returned to me from the (successful) OAuth
  authentication

Has anyone encountered this sort of error? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Did you figure this out? :D

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue today, my conclusions are as follows:

1. Unfortunately MailChimp (and many other companies offering OAuth2 endpoints) doesn't provide additional error information - `invalid_grant` is shown for a number of different scenarios.
2. In my case the issue was caused by a slight difference in `redirect_uri` - I didn't include the exact match in the token request. It's strict and query parameters must be included and must match, too.
3. Including a wrong authorisation code unfortunately results in the same error as point above.

Comment: Having the same issue, and still can't work out what's causing it. Sending the exact same redirect URI in both cases, valid client ID/secret, and the exact code as received from the authorization. Super unhelpful error message...

Answer (score 2):

My issue with `invalid_grant` was caused by using `encodeURIComponent` on the redirect URI, and then passing this encoded value to the configuration of the request object. This essentially caused double encoding, which caused the redirect URI's to mismatch and that resulted in this error.